# What is values of exponential in complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a doubt about value of $e^{z}$ at $\infty$ in one of my book they are mentioning that as $\lim_{z \to \infty} e^z  \to \infty $

But in another book they are saying it doesn't exist.I am confused now

As we can see $e^{z}$ is entire function then as $z \to \infty $ then $e^{z}$ must go to $\infty$

Please help.

Comment: In general if a limit tends to $\infty$ it's said to not exist, since $\infty$ is not a number!

Comment: @RScrlli There is such thing as meromorphic functions. It is ok to ask whether the limit $\lim\limits_{z\to\infty}f(z)=\infty$ holds for a meromorphic function. Exponential function is not meromorphic at $\infty$ anyway.

Comment: @edm I thought the question was more simple, thanks for clarifying that to me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$|e^{i2\pi n}|=1$  for all $n$  and $|i2\pi n| \to \infty$. So it is not true that $|e^{z}| \to \infty$ as $|z| \to \infty$. Of course the limit is $\infty$ when you take limit through $\{1,2,..\}$ so the limit of $e^{z}$ as $|z| \to \infty$ does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

$e^z$ has an essential singularity at $z=\infty$ so we would not say $\lim\limits_{z\to\infty}e^z=\infty$, but instead we say the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

In real analysis,
$$
\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}e^x=\infty
$$
because the limit is taken along the positive real axis. Similarly,
$$
\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}e^x=0
$$
because the limit is taken along the negative real axis.

However, in complex analysis, $\infty$ is taken to be the point added to make the [one-point compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension) of the complex plane (the [Riemann Sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere)). $e^z$ takes on all non-zero complex values in any neighborhood of $\infty$. Therefore, $\lim\limits_{z\to\infty}e^z$ does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I think $e^x$ goes to infinity, while $e^z$ or $(e^i)^x$ spins around the unit circle at the rate of the distance around a unit circle.

The letter 'z' could mean Real Integer or Complex number:

z = integers = ( -inf, ..., -2,-1,0,1,2....inf)

z = complex = x + iy

Which are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are working on extended complex plane i.e. $\mathbb C\cup$ {$\infty$}, you can use the substitution $z=\frac{1}{w}$ and investigate the behaviour at $w=0$.

$e^{1/w}$ has essential singularity at $w=0$ and *Big Picard's theorem* says that it will take all values on $\mathbb C$ in the neighborhood of $w=0$ with atmost one exception.